# Getting latest based on column condition in Spark Scala is not working

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Data Frame

```
+-------------+-------------------------+--------------+--------+---------+--------------------+------------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
|DataPartition|TimeStamp                |OrganizationID|SourceID|AuditorID|AuditorEnumerationId|AuditorOpinionCode|AuditorOpinionId|IsPlayingAuditorRole|IsPlayingCSRAuditorRole|IsPlayingTaxAdvisorRole|FFAction|!||AuditorOpinionOnInternalControlCode|AuditorOpinionOnGoingConcernCode|AuditorOpinionOnInternalControlsId|AuditorOpinionOnGoingConcernId|
+-------------+-------------------------+--------------+--------+---------+--------------------+------------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
|Japan        |2018-05-03T09:52:48+00:00|4295876589    |194     |2719     |3023331             |AOP               |3010542         |true                |false                  |true                   |O|!|       |null                               |null                            |null                              |null                          |
|Japan        |2018-05-03T09:52:48+00:00|4295876589    |195     |16157    |1002485247          |UWE               |3010547         |true                |false                  |false                  |O|!|       |null                               |null                            |null                              |null                          |
|Japan        |2018-05-03T07:36:47+00:00|4295876589    |196     |3252     |3024053             |ONC               |3020538         |true                |false                  |true                   |O|!|       |null                               |null                            |null                              |null                          |
|Japan        |2018-05-03T07:36:47+00:00|4295876589    |195     |5937     |3026578             |NOP               |3010543         |true                |false                  |true                   |O|!|       |null                               |null                            |null                              |null                          |
|Japan        |2018-05-03T08:10:19+00:00|4295876589    |196     |null     |null                |null              |null            |null                |null                   |null                   |D|!|       |null                               |null                            |null                              |null                          |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------------+--------+---------+--------------------+------------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

This is what i am doing to get

```
val windowSpec2 = Window.partitionBy("OrganizationID", "SourceID").orderBy(unix_timestamp($"TimeStamp", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").cast("timestamp").desc)
    val latestForEachKey = latestForEachKey1.withColumn("tobefiltered", first("FFAction|!|").over(windowSpec2))
      .filter($"tobefiltered" === "I|!|" || $"tobefiltered" === "O|!|" || ($"tobefiltered" === "D|!|" && $"FFAction|!|" === "D|!|"))
      .drop("tobefiltered", "TimeStamp")
```

Output Data frame

```
+-------------+--------------+--------+---------+--------------------+------------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
|DataPartition|OrganizationID|SourceID|AuditorID|AuditorEnumerationId|AuditorOpinionCode|AuditorOpinionId|IsPlayingAuditorRole|IsPlayingCSRAuditorRole|IsPlayingTaxAdvisorRole|FFAction|!||AuditorOpinionOnInternalControlCode|AuditorOpinionOnGoingConcernCode|AuditorOpinionOnInternalControlsId|AuditorOpinionOnGoingConcernId|
+-------------+--------------+--------+---------+--------------------+------------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
|Japan        |4295876589    |195     |16157    |1002485247          |UWE               |3010547         |true                |false                  |false                  |O|!|       |null                               |null                            |null                              |null                          |
|Japan        |4295876589    |195     |5937     |3026578             |NOP               |3010543         |true                |false                  |true                   |O|!|       |null                               |null                            |null                              |null                          |
|Japan        |4295876589    |196     |null     |null                |null              |null            |null                |null                   |null                   |D|!|       |null                               |null                            |null                              |null                          |
|Japan        |4295876589    |194     |2719     |3023331             |AOP               |3010542         |true                |false                  |true                   |O|!|       |null                               |null                            |null                              |null                          |
+-------------+--------------+--------+---------+--------------------+------------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Here i am not expecting two rows for same value of Columns `OrganizationID` and `SourceID`

Here is another example

```
uniqueFundamentalSet    PeriodId    SourceId    StatementTypeCode   StatementCurrencyId UpdateReason_updateReasonId UpdateReasonComment UpdateReasonComment_languageId  UpdateReasonEnumerationId   FFAction|!| DataPartition   PartitionYear   TimeStamp
192730230775    297 182 INC 500186  6   UpdateReasonToDelete    505074  3019685 I|!|    Japan   2017    2018-05-10T09:57:29+00:00
192730230775    297 182 INC 500186  6   UpdateReasonToDelete    505074  3019685 I|!|    Japan   2017    2018-05-10T10:00:40+00:00
192730230775    297 182 INC 500186  null    null    null    null    O|!|    Japan   2017    2018-05-10T10:11:15+00:00
192730230775    310 182 INC 500186  null    null    null    null    O|!|    Japan   2018    2018-05-10T08:30:53+00:00
```

And this is what I am doing

```
val windowSpec2 = Window.partitionBy("uniqueFundamentalSet", "PeriodId", "SourceId", "StatementTypeCode", "StatementCurrencyId").orderBy(unix_timestamp($"TimeStamp", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").cast("timestamp").desc)
    val latestForEachKey = latestForEachKey1.withColumn("tobefiltered", row_number().over(windowSpec2))
      .filter(($"FFAction|!|" === "I|!|" || $"FFAction|!|" === "O|!|" || ($"FFAction|!|" === "D|!|" && $"FFAction|!|" === "D|!|")) && $"tobefiltered" === 1)
      .drop("tobefiltered", "TimeStamp")
```

But I am not getting the latest record .

I am getting this

```
192730230775    297 182 INC 500186  6   UpdateReasonToDelete    505074  3019685 I|!|    Japan   2017    2018-05-10T10:00:40+00:00
```

But the latest is record that has this time stamp `2018-05-10T10:11:15+00:00`

So the final output should be

```
192730230775    297 182 INC 500186  null    null    null    null    O|!|    Japan   2017    2018-05-10T10:11:15+00:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`first` is *an aggregation function* but since you have used it *with `window` funtion, the output of aggregation is applied to every row again*.

All you need is `row_number()` inbuilt function to be used with `window` function and to `filter` later on as

```
val windowSpec2 = Window.partitionBy("OrganizationID", "SourceID").orderBy(unix_timestamp($"TimeStamp", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").cast("timestamp").desc)
val latestForEachKey = latestForEachKey1.withColumn("tobefiltered", row_number().over(windowSpec2))
  .filter(($"FFAction|!|" === "I|!|" || $"FFAction|!|" === "O|!|" || ($"FFAction|!|" === "D|!|" && $"FFAction|!|" === "D|!|")) && $"tobefiltered" === 1)
  .drop("tobefiltered", "TimeStamp")

latestForEachKey.show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+-------------+--------------+--------+---------+--------------------+------------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
|DataPartition|OrganizationID|SourceID|AuditorID|AuditorEnumerationId|AuditorOpinionCode|AuditorOpinionId|IsPlayingAuditorRole|IsPlayingCSRAuditorRole|IsPlayingTaxAdvisorRole|FFAction|!||AuditorOpinionOnInternalControlCode|AuditorOpinionOnGoingConcernCode|AuditorOpinionOnInternalControlsId|AuditorOpinionOnGoingConcernId|
+-------------+--------------+--------+---------+--------------------+------------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
|Japan        |4295876589    |195     |16157    |1002485247          |UWE               |3010547         |true                |false                  |false                  |O|!|       |null                               |null                            |null                              |null                          |
|Japan        |4295876589    |196     |null     |null                |null              |null            |null                |null                   |null                   |D|!|       |null                               |null                            |null                              |null                          |
|Japan        |4295876589    |194     |2719     |3023331             |AOP               |3010542         |true                |false                  |true                   |O|!|       |null                               |null                            |null                              |null                          |
+-------------+--------------+--------+---------+--------------------+------------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
```